# How to use Tor for scripts?

Tags: configuration

Say I wrote a script that uses Internet connection. What's the right approach to redirect it to tor so I stay anonymous? Sorry for a silly question I'm new to Tor. Thank you.

Comment: What application are you running the script through? You can go into that application's internet settings and make a proxy to the Tor network at port 9150.

Comment: @Swangie It is a Python script.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639742/ddg

Comment: @Swangie Thanks I will check it out.